# Plotly Dash Table deletable and clearable does not work with custom paging

Tags: plotly-dash

Clearable and deletable does not work when custom page action (custom paging) is implemented. Is there any way to enable those feature or implement custom logic for deleting and clearing the columns when custom paging is implemented?

```
dash==2.0.0
dash-table==5.0.0

dash_table.DataTable(
  id='pricing-table',
  columns=[],
  data=[],
  editable=True,,
  column_selectable="multi",
  fixed_rows={"headers": True, 'data':0},
  fill_width=True,
  tooltip_duration = None,
  page_current=0,
  page_size=PAGE_SIZE,
  page_action='custom'
```